# Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $p$ is a prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

If $a\in R-p$ and $b \in p-{p}^2$, is it true that $ab \in p-{p}^2$? I can see this is obviously true in Noetherian domain but I am not sure if it is true in general (this claim about Noetherian condition was proven to be wrong by the example below).

Comment: Note that $p/p^2$ is an $R/p$-module. This would ask if there is a nonzero $a\in R/p$ and non-zero $b\in p/p^2$ such that $ab=0.$  Not sure if that helps. Also, $R/p$ is an integral domain.

Comment: From the answer below, it appears that you were wrong about the Noetherian claim. Why is it obviously true for Noetherian rings?

Comment: I think I made a mistake in my wrong proof

Comment: The question is roughly related to whether $p$ induces a discrete valuation of $R$, which is also related to whether $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is nonsingular at $p$.  And indeed, in rschweib's answer, $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is singular at the origin.  (Though certainly, the relation is only tight in the case of curves, which $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is not.)

Answer (score 5):

Consider $R=F[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ with $P=(x,z)$.

Then $y\in R\setminus P$ and $x\in P\setminus P^2$, but $xy=z^2\in P^2$.

Comment: Maybe it's worthy to mention that the question is equivalent to the following: if $p$ is a prime ideal, is then $p^2$ a $p$-primary ideal? And this has been asked and answered for few times on M.SE, the above example being the most used.